# Rewrite CPT child page URL to support query var

Tags: custom-post-types, rewrite-rules

I am having some issues with rewrite rules. I have a URL like this:

http://www.domain.com/post-type/parent-page/child-page/section-id

Which I want to treat via query vars like

http://www.domain.com/post-type/parent-page/child-page?section=section-id

I have this tag and rule set:

```
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);
function custom_rewrite_tag() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%section%', '([^(&)]+)');
}

add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('post-type/(.+?)/(.+?)/(.+?)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]/$matches[2]&section=$matches[3]','top');
}
```

However the page is 404ing, and outputting `$wp->matched_query` shows that it isn't selecting my rule, but one further down the list of rules (that was auto created by WP). It's actually matching the last rule in the `$wp_rewrite->wp_rewrite_rules()` array that starts with `post-type`.

Weird thing is that if I change the rule to:

```
add_rewrite_rule('post-type/(.+?)/(.+?)/(.+?)/?$', 'index.php?p=1234567&extravar=$matches[1]/$matches[2]&section=$matches[3]','top');
```

(i.e., purposely 404ing the page by going to an ID that doesn't exist, and just passing along the vars for reference) `$wp->matched_query` shows my regex, and the url is as it should be (`index.php?p=1234567&extravar=parent-page/child-page&section=section-id`)

What is the reason why my redirect URL is causing the rewrite engine to skip over my rule? Is something up with `pagename`?

**Edit**: Additional tests have revealed that going directly to http://www.domain.com/post-type/?pagename=parent-page/child-page&section=section-id works. so `pagename` is apparently valid.

**Edit 2**: More testing, changed the `add_rewrite_rule` call to check for post type as well...No Dice:

```
add_rewrite_rule('post-type/(.+?)/(.+?)/(.+?)/?$', 'index.php?post_type=post-type&pagename=$matches[1]/$matches[2]&section=$matches[3]','top');
```

I have also tried just using `$matches[2]`, still not working:

```
add_rewrite_rule('post-type/(.+?)/(.+?)/(.+?)/?$', 'index.php?post_type=post-type&pagename=$matches[2]&section=$matches[3]','top');
```

The strange thing still is that building these URLs manually (as in filling in the query string values) actually loads the correct page. Don't know what the Rewrite API would make that any different.

Comment: Do 'post-type' is present on the permalink structure at WordPress permalink options? If so, maybe it's duplicating when you specify it on the custom rule. It may be looking for `post-type/post-type/(.+?)/(.+?)/(.+?)/?$`

Comment: That probably isn't it, since the regex works when I change the URL to purposely 404. It is capturing the URL correctly, but for some reason the original URL I redirect to is causing the rule to be skipped over.

Comment: have you tried setting a `post_type`? I'll guess that `pagename` assumes the `page` post type if nothing is set.

Comment: @Milo That's a good suggestion, but no dice. I edited the post with what I tried, and I''m still getting 404'd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after a lot of playing around, I found this:

1. The regex it was matching (while skipping over my rule) was `practice-area/(.+?)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$`

   - This had a `$matches` array of 2: `parent-page/child-page` and a `number` that follows that, which is blank since there isn't one in the URL I was trying to build.
   - Also the URL it was redirecting to was `index.php?post-type=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]`. I didn't realize that `post-type` could be a query var key. So that's what ultimately got me on the right path.
2. So I decided to directly copy that, but instead of looking for a number I look for any character

   - I used `post-type/(.+?)(?:/(.+))?/?$`
   - This didn't work because I ended up with `$matches[1] = parent-page` and `$matches[2] = child-page/section-id`
3. So, with a bit more tweaking, and messing with the laziness of the capture groups, I came up with `post-type/(.+)/(.+?)/?$`, which successfully superseded the regex in (1) above.

   - `$matches[1] = parent-page/child-age` and `$matches[2] = section-id`

The final rewrite rule is:

```
add_rewrite_rule('post-type/(.+)/(.+?)/?$', 'index.php?post-type=$matches[1]&section=$matches[2]','top');
```